# Why does Stack Overflow recommend the badge for which I do not have enough reputation?

Tags: discussion

Currently I have 17 reputation on Stack Overflow, and my next badge recommendation is 'Commentator'.

However, in order to comment, I need to have at least 50 rep. The only alternative is to comment stuff on my own questions.

Comment: Thanks for finding a duplicate.

Comment: By the way, are comments on meta also counted for the commentator badge?

Answer (score -1):

The badge system doesn't consider rules like that, when suggesting new badges.

The system is intentionally naïve, probably in order to reduce required processing power.

Comment: Not really as you can earn this badge with 1 rep by commenting on your own questions/answers.

Comment: @RobertLongson: I completely forgot about that. Good find on the dupe, by the way.